Bulging, dropping ceiling: is this a problem?

So this is a group home I work at and there are many cracks and lines throughout the house. I can’t explain what is happening in this image. Do I need to worry about it falling?

A picture from farther away would be more helpful.
What is shown looks more like a failure in the drywall, possibly from a leak  (water intrusion).  It looks like a repair was attempted also. The bulging could be water getting between the paint and drywall.
There is nothing that shows this is structural at this point. The indication is there is an issue with the ceiling at that location and most likely something mor cosmetic.  That said, you should keep an eye on it. Any growth of cracks or increase in the bulge and you should have a professional take a look.  Not necessary an engineer, but a handyman or drywaller, or builder that can give a better examination.
Knowing what is above that corner can give some insight as well. For example, and AC unit could be dripping condensation and that could be the source of the issue, or a leak from a bathroom.

Though depending on age, that may not actually be drywall.

All buildings settle over time. Small cracks and bulges gradually forming are normal and do not indicate that the building is in danger of falling down. If the crack or bulge forms fast and keeps getting bigger, though, that's a cause for concern.
The only way to be for sure would be to hire a structural engineer to come out and inspect the building. They have the skills to determine whether there is a problem with the building.
You can also measure and record & take pictures of cracks or bulges at regular intervals. These records will quantify the changes in the problem, making it easier to tell if the problem is getting bigger.
You can search on DIY.SE for "crack in wall" or "crack concern" to see the myriad posts about cracks in walls and see what is considered normal vs dangerous.

It has gotten deeper. It’s about 3 inches deep. I couldn’t add a photo of that whole wall but the wall to the side of it has that bulging. It looks like on every beam and those are just recent.

That does sound concerning. Time to talk to the bosses...
